# Inherit roles_path (or another value) from Ansible config with a lower precedence

Tags: inheritance, ansible, config

So the question is relatively broad, as I want to know how to have a more general config that is extended if needed by a more specific config. But I will exemplify it on a much simpler use case. I may have certain user-wide ansible config, but then for a certain project I'd like to use an additional directory for roles (e.g. `roles/`) in that project.

I would imagine that I could specify something like

```
roles_path = my_roles:{{ROLES_PATH}}
```

But I completely failed to get something like this to work (or to find any solutions by googling)

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***" I have a user Ansible config. For a certain project, I'd like to use an additional directory for roles."***

A: Take a look at [DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-roles-path). There are only two options for how to configure paths in which Ansible will search for roles:

- configuration file, or
- environment variable ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH

Given the user configuration, for example

```ini
shell> cat /home/admin/.ansible.cfg
[defaults]
roles_path = $HOME/.ansible/roles
inventory = $PWD/hosts
```

use an additional directory for roles

```bash
shell> tree /export/ansible/roles/
/export/ansible/roles/
└── test_1
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat /export/ansible/roles/test_1/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: role_path
```

The only option for keeping the user configuration and adding the additional roles path is setting the environment variable ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH

```bash
ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/ansible/roles
```

You can either

- Create a script and set it for the session, or
- Create a wrapper and set it for the run-time

---

Note: Unfortunately, [ansible-runner](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/runner/en/latest/intro/#intro) overrides ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH. See the last section.

---

**1. script**

Create a script in the project directory. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat create-script.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_roles: [/export/ansible/roles]
    roles_path: "{{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') + my_roles }}"

  tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/.set-env"
        content: |
          export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH={{ roles_path|unique|join(':') }}
```

creates the below script in the current directory

```bash
shell> cat .set-env 
export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/ansible/roles
```

Use the script and set the environment

```bash
shell> . .set-env 
shell> set | grep ANSIBLE
ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/ansible/roles
```

---

**2. wrapper**

Create a wrapper in the project directory. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat create-wrapper.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_roles: [/export/ansible/roles]
    roles_path: "{{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') + my_roles }}"

  tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/.ansible-playbook"
        mode: a+x
        content: |
          #!/usr//bin/bash
          export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH={{ roles_path|unique|join(':') }}
          /usr/bin/ansible-playbook $@
```

creates the wrapper in the current directory

```bash
shell> cat .ansible-playbook 
#!/usr//bin/bash
export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/ansible/roles
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook $@
```

Example of a project

```bash
shell> tree -a .
.
├── .ansible-playbook
├── create-wrapper.yml
├── hosts
├── pb1.yml
└── pb2.yml
```

Without the environment variable, the additional path is not available

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH
DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH(/home/admin/.ansible.cfg) = ['/home/admin/.ansible/roles']
```

Use the wrapper. For example, the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: localhost

  roles:
    - test_1
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ./.ansible-playbook pb2.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test_1 : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "role_path": "/export/ansible/roles/test_1"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Note: ansible-runner ignores ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH in  env/envvars

You can put the environment variable into the file [env/envvars](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/runner/en/latest/intro/#env-envvars). Quoting:

> ... environment variables that will be added to the environment at run-time

Example of a project for testing

```bash
shell> pwd
/scratch/tmp1/test-019

shell> tree .
.
├── env
│   └── envvars
├── hosts
└── project
    ├── pb1.yml
    └── pb2.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat env/envvars 
---
ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH: /home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/ansible/roles
```

```yaml
shell> cat project/pb2.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  roles:
    - test_1
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work

```bash
shell> ansible-runner run ./project -p pb2.yml
ERROR! the role 'test_1' was not found in /export/scratch/tmp1/test-019/project/roles:/home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/scratch/tmp1/test-019/project

The error appears to be in '/export/scratch/tmp1/test-019/project/pb2.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - test_1
      ^ here
```

Setting ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH in CLI works as expected

```bash
shell> ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/home/admin/.ansible/roles:/export/ansible/roles ansible-runner run ./project -p pb2.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

If the roles are already residing in that project, you don't need to change anything.

From the roles documentation:

> By default, Ansible looks for roles in the following locations:
>
> in collections, if you are using them
>
> in a directory called `roles/`, relative to the playbook file
>
> in the configured `roles_path`. The default search path is
> `~/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles`.
>
> in the directory where the playbook file is located

For some reason it isn't specified on that page, but you can set the path via [`ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH) environment variable.

Also, if you're running the playbooks from the project root, you can just put the `ansible.cfg` file there. That way you can have the whole configuration customized for certain projects.

From the [configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file) documentation:

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be
> searched for in the following order:
>
> `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (environment variable if set)
>
> `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
>
> `~/.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
>
> `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`
>
> Ansible will process the above list and use the first file found, all
> others are ignored.